# ExtJS TreeGrid Auto Column Widths

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How can I make the columns use auto-width in an ExtJS TreeGrid?

I am using ExtJS 3.3.1; and TreeGrid is a ux extended from TreePanel.

Comment: It's a nightmare...  use Extjs 4.1 with their built in treegrid if at all possible.

Comment: Does the 4.1 TreeGrid have auto-sizing for columns?

Comment: The example is at: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/tree/treegrid.html but there does not appear to be API documentation

Comment: yeah, it's built right in, the treegrid is no longer a ux component, you can do anything with it that you can do with a grid, it's just an extension of grid, so it provides the same exact logic.

Comment: If you can switch to 4.1, I can show you how to do what you want as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if I can possibly get the size of the width of the panel, and may be set the width for each column dynamically or something.

Comment: @Reimius I am now using 4.2.1.744. Does the answer involve using the flex attribute on the column headers?

Comment: yes, you can achieve what you want using flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExtJS 4.2.1, the result can be achieved by using the "flex" attribute on the column headers.

Thanks to @Reimius for the clue.